# Having an issue trying to identify an Integer

Tags: java, integer

I can normally identify an integer by typing in int something = 0; to initialize or something.

This time I would like to get an integer like I do a String from a JtextArea.

```
            String strcname = cname.getText();
            **int strage = age.getInt();**
            String stremail = email.getText();
            String strphone = phone.getText();
```

Obviously I am getting an error here but not sure how to have this excepted as an integer any ideas?

Comment: Text areas are... well, text.

Comment: `int strage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText());`  Make sure you add exceptions to catch when its not an `int` or it is `null`

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
int strage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText());
```

Comment: +1, Just a side note - in the actual code you'll want to gracefully handle the NumberFormatException that gets thrown if the user enters something other than 0-9.

Comment: Absolutely, also text areas are multiline so `JTextField` is probably a better fit here.

Comment: Also use `int strage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText(), 10);` to avoid unwanted convertions